# HOW TO GET DATA FROM EXCEL USING PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

HI all i am new to PHP (Beginner) i have one excel file. the file will be look like

```
    A3      B3    C3         D3           E3 
   s.no    name   sex       DOB          Address
    1      SAM     M    19-11-1990     2-75,Jln Klang Lama,KL,58132
```

now i have to use PHP and print B3 And E3 like

```
 SAM
 2-75,
 Jln Klang Lama,
 KL,58132
```

is it possible to get out put using PHP..can give me a Idea how to do?? then i will try coding for my program TQ

Answer (score 0):

excel files are having xml special you need to filter data from that xml and xl files are compressed combinaation of files first you need to decompress that read the main xml there will be library for that on internet search for it

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a **library** then,

[**PHPExcel**](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) a fantastic library for php to consume excel.. it helps awesomely to  Read, Write and Create Excel documents in PHP.

I have used it in no of projects and in freelancing ... great library. You need to first understand how it integrates with php ... rest is easy :)

link : **[phpExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)** enjoy :)

if you are looking for pure **[php - excel integration](http://devzone.zend.com/27/reading-and-writing-spreadsheets-with-php/)**